# Update child div's image size to never exceed parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to **detect the image size** when it is placed in the main image and if it's above a certain height, make the image a certain height.  I'm having issues with this because right now, it seems to only detect the first image and is **currently not responsive** when I choose another image by clicking the thumbnail.

All images when put in the main-image area should be centered.

The javascript doesn't work but I think I'm headed in the right direction hopefully.

```js
$('.thumb-box').click(function() {

  $(this).parent('.main-image').attr('src', '.thumb-box > img').fadeIn();

});

//Resize image
  $('.main-image').each(function() {
  if ($(this).height() > 550) { $(this).addClass('higher-than-max'); }
  else if ($(this).height() <= 550) {$(this).addClass('not-higher-than-max');}
});
```

```css
.parent{
  border:1px solid purple;
  height:100%;
  width:80%;
  float:Right;
}
.child{
  border:1px solid red;
  height:100%;
  background:gray;
  text-align:center;
}
.child-img{
display:inline-block;
max-width:100%;
margin:0 auto;
}
.image-wrapper{
  width:100%;
  background:orange;
}
.thumbnails img{
width:auto;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
.thumbnails{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  
}
.thumb-box{
  height:40%;
  width:40%;
  display:inline-block;
  background:red;
}
.higher-than-max{
  max-height:500px;
  width:auto;
}
.not-higher-than-max{
  max-height:100%;
  width:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/pokemon/images/b/b1/025Pikachu_XY_anime_3.png/revision/latest?cb=20140902050035" alt="374x333" class="main-image">
        <div class="thumbnails">
          <div class="thumb-box"> 
          <img src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/pokemon/images/b/b1/025Pikachu_XY_anime_3.png/revision/latest?cb=20140902050035" alt="374x333" class="child-img">        </div>
          <div class="thumb-box"> 
          <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/unnbgkdbmsszmazgxkmr.jpg" alt="800x450" class="child-img"></div>
          <div class="thumb-box">  
          <img src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/scratchpad/images/0/02/Pikachu.gif/revision/latest?cb=20150217015901" alt="" class="child-img">
          </div>
          <div class="thumb-box">
                <img src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/0/0d/025Pikachu.png/250px-025Pikachu.png" alt="" class="child-img">
          </div>
        </div>
        

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have couple issues in your `.click()` function:

1. the `.main-image` is *not* parent of `thumb-box`, so you need to use `parents()` <sup>(**1**)</sup> instead of `parent()` to select a higher-level parent then navigate to the big image -*and it'll be `parents('.image-wrapper').find('.main-image')`* .
2. this `.attr('src', '.thumb-box > img')` will inject the *string* ".thumb-box > img" into the `src` attribute of the big image instead of injecting the source of the image in the `.thumb-box` into the big image `src` attribute.

Change it to this

[**JS Fiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/wsu3mv5c/)

```
$('.thumb-box').click(function() {

  // grab the src of the image nested in the just clicked tumb-box
  var theSRC = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
  // using parents() we grab the .image-wrapper, then the main-image nested inside it
  // and inject the stored src value of the thumb-box image into the main-image source
  $(this).parents('.image-wrapper').find('.main-image').attr('src', theSRC).fadeIn();

});
```

---

For the second issue "*having max height of 550px*" you can do it simply in CSS without the need for the resize code in javascript so remove the unnecessary code <sup>(**2**)</sup>, just add this to your CSS <sup>(**3**)</sup> :

[**JS Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/wsu3mv5c/1/)

```
.main-image {
  max-height: 550px;
  width: auto;
}
```

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<sup>(**1**)</sup> https://api.jquery.com/parents/

<sup>(**2**)</sup> Beside removing `//Resize image $('.main-image').each(...)` also remove `.higher-than-max` and `.not-higher-than-max` classes from your CSS you don't need any of them.

<sup>(**3**)</sup> to see it more clear in the fiddle change `max-height: 550px;` to `250px` or `300px`

Comment: Thank you very much, I edited my code accordingly, I'm still trying to figure out the second issue.

Comment: You welcome, but you shouldn't chage the code in the question this will make the question meaningless without it's original problem

Comment: @Snorlax, check my updated answer now that fixes the second issue too, have a look at **JS Fiddle 2** in my answer as the one fixes all issues you had